# How to pass parameters values to the ViewModel in MVVM pattern?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, imageview, viewmodel

I am developing an android app with MVVM pattern in kotlin language,
my questions are how to pass EditText value to the function which is located in the ViewModel? and how to pick an image from the gallery and send it to this ViewModel?
any help with code if you please?
Actually, I did not like MVVM pattern, but the customer wants it in this pattern....thanks.

Comment: Share some code

Comment: Code for what ? I am asking for some code :-)

Answer (score 1):

It would have been handy if you had shared some code.

Below is what I would do.

Inside the `ViewModel` create a `MutableLiveData` object and declare it in the `layout` file like below.

In the `ViewModel`,

```
val yourVariable : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

In the `layout` file,

First add the `ViewModel` like below.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.example.app.YourViewModel" />
</data>
```

Then to the `EditText`,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/yourID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={viewmodel.yourVariable}"
/>
```

Then you can use `yourVariable` inside your `ViewModel`.

Comment: you mean dataBinding, I know it but I mean the image, I need some how to pick up an image from the gallery and send it with retrofit library, the major problem is I don not know how to pick an image and have it in the viewModel... if you what I mean.

Comment: you mean dataBinding, I know it but I mean the image, I need some how to pick up an image from the gallery and send it with retrofit library, the major problem is I don not know how to pick an image and have it in the viewModel... if you what I mean.

Comment: @AliAhmed your first question is how to pass EditText value to the function which is located in the viewmodel?" and the answer is above. 
For the second question which is "how to pick an image from gallery and send it to this viewmodel" you can pass the image data via a function inside the viewModel from the Activity.

Comment: more explanation if you please? 
any code? or resource ?